# Debugging Spring resource servlet - how to?

Tags: spring

I am having great troubles accessing dojox within SPRING-JS. SPRING-JS-RESOURSES is accessed via Spring resource servlet.

How would I iterate through the /resources/ and list what is there?

Thanks

BTW I am in MyEclipse for Spring 10. Not using Maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the entry point you are looking for

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler
```